# Ansible using Having same host in multiple groups but while running playbooy even after specifying groupname its taking another groups variable

Tags: ansible, ansible-playbook

We have Apache setup chrooted, so we can multiple apache on single directory for multiple httpd instance. I have added all the different groups with the instance name in inventory but their hosts are same.

While I am running tasks on one httpd instance, it takes groups vars of different group even though the hosts are same in all groups.

Comment: Just add a custom name for host and bind to ip using ansible_host. The response is here. https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/intro_inventory.html#hosts-and-non-standard-ports

Answer (score 4):

This answer can help:
[Ansible same host on different groups with group_vars](https://serverfault.com/questions/966019/ansible-same-host-on-different-groups-with-group-vars/967186#967186)

Try overriding host variables each time it is required with "vars_files":

```
hosts: {{ group_name }}
vars_files:
 - group_vars/{{ group_name }}.yml
tasks:
```

Answer (score 2):

I have done another workaround.

I have added entries in `/etc/hosts` with different hostname but with same ips like below.

```
10.0.0.2 apache1
10.0.0.3 apache2
10.0.0.2 newapache1
10.0.0.3 newapache2
```

also i have added in inventory like below

```
[apache]
apache1
apache2

[newapache]
newapache1
newapache2
```

with same name you can create the groupvars with different details for same server.

Its not correct solution but for small setup its work great.