# Ansible same host on different groups with group_vars

Tags: ansible, ansible-playbook

I have an Ansible inventory like the following:

```
[group1]
host1.mydomain

[maingroup:children]
group1

[group2]
host1.mydomain
```

I need to declare the same host on different groups since in this host there are two similar services collocated.
In order to distinguish between the two services, I have created the following group vars:

```
group_vars/maingroup
---
servicepath: /service1/path

group_vars/group2
---
servicepath: /service2/path
```

When I first run a playbook with `hosts: maingroup`, then the same playbook with `hosts: group2`, it used the correct `servicepath` variable value each time (first run=`/service1/path`, second run=`/service2/path`).

However, in all subsequent retries when I run a playbook with `maingroup` I got the value `servicepath: /service2/path`

I only managed to run the playbook with correct variables with  `--extra-vars=@group_vars/group2` ansible-playbook parameter.

Could this be an Ansible bug or am I missing something?

Comment: could you show your ansible playbook?

Comment: This [reading](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_variables.html#variable-precedence-where-should-i-put-a-variable) might help, especially the note at the end of the chapter.

Comment: Just add a custom name for host and bind to ip using ansible_host. The response is here. https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/intro_inventory.html#hosts-and-non-standard-ports

Comment: @MihaiR Thanks. This could be a solution, although not so elegant.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The fact is that ansible binds the value of variables to the host, not to the group. That is, there can be only one value for one variable on one host.

Try this just to override the value of the variable on the host everytime:

```
---
- hosts: "{{ hosts }}"
  vars_files:
    - group_vars/{{ hosts }}.yml
  tasks:
  - name: my command
    command: "command with {{ servicepath }}"

- hosts: "{{ hosts }}"
  vars_files:
    - group_vars/{{ hosts }}.yml
  tasks:
  - name: my command
    command: "command with {{ servicepath }}"
```

where {{ hosts }} = "maingroup" or "group2"

Example:

```
---
- hosts: "maingroup"
  vars_files:
    - group_vars/maingroup.yml
  tasks:
  - name: my command
    command: "command with {{ servicepath }}"

- hosts: "group2"
  vars_files:
    - group_vars/group2.yml
  tasks:
  - name: my command
    command: "command with {{ servicepath }}"

- hosts: "maingroup"
  vars_files:
    - group_vars/maingroup.yml
  tasks:
  - name: my command
    command: "command with {{ servicepath }}"
```

Comment: That works, but is much error-prone. 

I'd recommend to use a random and unique hostname, combined with `ansible_ssh_host`, pointing to the real server. 

```
[db_gmbh_prod]
db_gmbh_prod_ ansible_ssh_host=1.2.3.4 ansible_ssh_user=root
```